# hc-sr04 stops on python after a very short while. F5 (run) and it works again, but only for a very short time again

Tags: python-3, sonic-pi

Here's the code, it communicates with Sonic Pi, don't know if that matters:

```
  import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import signal
import sys
from pythonosc import udp_client
from pythonosc import osc_message_builder
#from scipy.interpolate import interpld

# use Raspberry Pi board pin numbers
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

# set GPIO Pins
pinTrigger = 18
pinEcho = 24
sender = udp_client.SimpleUDPClient('127.0.0.1', 4559)

def close(signal, frame):
    print("\nTurning off ultrasonic distance detection...\n")
    GPIO.cleanup() 
    sys.exit(0)

lastpitch1=60
lastpitch2=64
lastpitch3=67
lastpitch4=72
lastpitch5=69
pitch1 =60
pitch2 =64
pitch3 =67
pitch4 =72
pitch5 =69

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, close)

# set GPIO input and output channels
GPIO.setup(pinTrigger, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(pinEcho, GPIO.IN)


while True:
    # set Trigger to HIGH
    GPIO.output(pinTrigger, True)
    # set Trigger after 0.01ms to LOW
    time.sleep(0.00001)
    GPIO.output(pinTrigger, False)

    startTime = time.time()
    stopTime = time.time()

    abortTime = time.time() + 0.5

    while 0 == GPIO.input(pinEcho):
        startTime = time.time()
        if startTime > abortTime:
            exit

    abortTime = time.time() + 0.5

    while 1 == GPIO.input(pinEcho):
        stopTime = time.time()
        if stopTime > abortTime:
            exit

    # time difference between start and arrival
    TimeElapsed = stopTime - startTime
    # multiply with the sonic speed (34300 cm/s)
    # and divide by 2, because there and back
    distance = (TimeElapsed * 34300) / 2

    print ("Distance: %.1f cm" % distance)
    if distance < 10:
            pitch1=lastpitch1
            pitch2=lastpitch2
            pitch3=lastpitch3
            pitch4=lastpitch4
            pitch5=lastpitch5
    elif 10 < distance < 50:
            pitch1 = 60
            pitch2 = 64
            pitch3 = 67
            pitch4 = 72
            pitch5 = 69
            lastpitch1=pitch1
            lastpitch2=pitch2
            lastpitch3=pitch3
            lastpitch4=pitch4
            lastpitch5=pitch5
    elif 51 < distance < 100:
            pitch1 = 65
            pitch2 = 69
            pitch3 = 72
            pitch4 = 75
            pitch5 = 74
            lastpitch1=pitch1
            lastpitch2=pitch2
            lastpitch3=pitch3
            lastpitch4=pitch4
            lastpitch5=pitch5
    elif 101 < distance < 150:
            pitch1 = 67
            pitch2 = 71
            pitch3 = 74
            pitch4 = 65
            pitch5 = 76
            lastpitch1=pitch1
            lastpitch2=pitch2
            lastpitch3=pitch3
            lastpitch4=pitch4
            lastpitch5=pitch5
    elif 150 < distance:
            pitch1 = lastpitch1
            pitch2 = lastpitch2
            pitch3 = lastpitch3
            pitch4 = lastpitch4
            pitch5 = lastpitch5
    sender.send_message('/note_a', pitch1-24)
    sender.send_message('/note_b', pitch2-24)
    sender.send_message('/note_c', pitch3-24)
    sender.send_message('/note_d', pitch4-24)
    sender.send_message('/note_e', pitch5-24)
    #print ("Pitch: " + pitch1 + ", Pitch2: " + pitch2 + ", Pitch3: " + pitch3)
    time.sleep(.0001)
```

Comment: Anybody's got anything to add? :)

Answer (score 1):

This code just does not work on the Raspberry Pi.  It was probably copied from Arduino code with no understanding of the difference between the two systems.

Arduino: single user, single running program.

Pi: multi-user, multi-tasking operating system.

```py
# save start time
while 0 == GPIO.input(pinEcho):
    startTime = time.time()

# save time of arrival
while 1 == GPIO.input(pinEcho):
    stopTime = time.time()
```

On the Pi it is likely that the code will eventually get stuck in one of those while loops.

The most likely point is the first.  The freeze scenario is the program sends the trigger and then gets scheduled out.  By the time the program  is rescheduled the trigger pulse has been completed and the echo has been received.

You need to timeout each of those while loops, either with a timeout or just execute them a maximum number of times.

```py
abortTime = time.time() + 0.5

while 0 == GPIO.input(pinEcho):
     startTime = time.time()
     if startTime > abortTime:
        exit

abortTime = time.time() + 0.5

while 1 == GPIO.input(pinEcho):
    stopTime = time.time()
    if stopTime > abortTime:
        exit
```

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty much a hack when it comes to these things, so thanks for all the help!! (I'm mainly a music teacher ahah). I modified the code as you suggested and the program presents the same interruptions. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: That was not intended as criticism of you.  This code has been around for years and is widely copied on many web sites dedicated to the Pi.  Basically if you see a site which uses that code then it is not a site to be trusted for software.

Comment: Could you post the full amended code?  There may be other errors as well as the obvious ones.

Comment: Ah ok! Dw :) I didn't take it like that :)

Comment: ok i just edited the one at the top

Comment: *bump?* + @joan anymore help? I think since it took me a while to reply the last time, you might not have caught it yesterday, but made it: I updated the code at the very top! in any case thanks for all the help so far! :) :)